# C#: how to declare variable inside a Loop using a index. Pseudo Code ` For (int i...) {MapPolyline map+i = new MapPolyline(); .....}

Tags: c#, loops, variable-declaration

I have seen at stackexchange some answers with C++ but I need the answer at C#, please.

I must use a loop to add several MapPolylines to a map. If I don't declare a new one the last MapPolyLine is  the only one that is shown.

```
for (int i = 0; i< collections.Count(); i++)
{
```

// PseudoCode  (Locs is a LocationCollection)

```
MapPolyline mapl(+i) = new MapPolyline();
                        mapl(+i).Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange);
                        mapl(+i).StrokeThickness = 2;
                        mapl(+i).Opacity = 0.8;
                      
                        mapl(+i).Locations = locs;
                        mymap.Children.Add(mapl+i);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Variable names must be known at compile time. If you want to map names at runtime, use a Map ("pun" intended)

Comment: Of course @knittl, I was thinking at code and not at compiler. Anyway you mentioned one thing I had never heard before ("There's an extra bit (pun intended) of compiler magic at work" as someone explains). Sorry, but my code was ok, but the order by of my sql was incorrect, My bad!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use multiple variables `mapl(+i)`. Just use one - `mapl`. Every iteration in the loop you will create *a new object* which you then add to some collection:

```
mymap.Children.Add(mapl);
```

So you will really have several of them. If you need to distinguish them by number, just add a field to the `MapPolyline` class, say, `Id`, and then just set it to `i` inside the loop:

```
mapl.Id = i;
```

Comment: Thks @Dmitry Arestov, you are right and my code was right also. The issue was the "order by" of my sql. My bad, sorry. Anyway your idea of extending MapPolyLine to incorporate Id is very useful for the future.
I was getting only one mappolyline and I thought BingMaps was overriding it at each iteration. Lesson learnt.